# Passing data to custom elements with React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, custom-element

I have a custom styled checkbox and that checkbox is included in a set of mapped data array.

```
{nfcArray && nfcArray.map((item, key) => {
     return (
          <tr class="hover">
             <td className="cell_style pl-3 pl-lg-5">
                <Row noGutters>
                    <Form.Check
                       required
                       name={item.cardId}
                       id={item.cardId}
                       as={customCheckBox}
                    />

                    <label>{item.cardId}</label>
                </Row>
            </td>
            <td className="cell_style pl-3 pl-lg-5">{item.name}</td>
          </tr>
      )

 })}
```

My `customCheckBox` is given inside the render method like follows

```
        const customCheckBox = React.forwardRef(
            () => {

                return (
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 pl-0" >
                        <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="" />
                        <label className="custom-control-label" for=""></label>
                    </div>
                );
            },
        );
```

I want to pass `item.cardId` to my custom element so i can use `item.cardId` as id for the checkbox input in the custom element.
How can i do this action? Is there a way to pass the `item.cardId` from `as={customCheckBox}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any props that are unknown to React-Bootstraps `Form.Check` and `CheckInput`Components will be passed along to your `customCheckBox` Component.
Try something like `cardId={item.cardId}` as additional prop for `Form.Check`:

```
<Form.Check
   required
   name={item.cardId}
   id={item.cardId}
   as={customCheckBox}
   cardId={item.cardId} />
```

```
const customCheckBox = React.forwardRef((props) => {
    return (
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 pl-0" >
        <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id={props.cardId} />
        <label className="custom-control-label" for=""></label>
        </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: Where should i add cardId={item.cardId} to and how to read it from the customCheckBox